# Which data type should i use to store a number this large "58176849671553176833344572581" in java?

Tags: java

So i am working on this code on a site but among the test cases one of them is so large that it can't fit in long type and when I move on to float or double answer ain't coming out in numerical form anymore

```
package uri;
import java.util.*;
public class Clutter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        long b=sc.nextLong();
        while(a!=0 && b!=0) {
        String aa=new String(Long.toString(b));
        String r="";
        for(int i=0;i<aa.length();i++) {
            int t=Character.getNumericValue(aa.charAt(i));
            if(a==t) {
                if(i==aa.length()-1 && r.length()==0) {
                    System.out.println(0);
                    return;
                }
                continue;
            }else {
                r+=(int)t;
            }
        }
        long re=Long.parseLong(r);
        System.out.println(re);
        a=sc.nextInt();
        b=sc.nextLong();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: What are you going to do with this number? Can you not store it as a String?

Comment: definitely not one of the primitive types. Is there any specific reason you need numbers this large? Do you need to perform numerical/mathematical operations on it?

Comment: i submitted this code on beecrowd and this was one of its input due to which my code not getting accepted and giving runtime error

Comment: You don't seem to be using any mathematical operations with the numbers you are receiving, so just store them as Strings instead. (And then use `next()` or `nextLine()` instead of `nextInt()`/`nextLong()`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use BigInteger for this:

```
var bigInt = new BigInteger("58176849671553176833344572581");

bigInt.add(new BigInteger("1234"));
bigInt.subtract(new BigInteger("1234"));
bigInt.divide(new BigInteger("1234"));
bigInt.multiply(new BigInteger("1234"));
bigInt.pow(1234);
// And more operations
```

See this Guide for more information: https://www.baeldung.com/java-biginteger
And also take a look at the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: @f1sh **If** it needs to be stored as a numerical value. That's a big if. OP doesn't seem to be performing any mathematical operations on the numbers. (Not to mention that if this is indeed the answer, there are already a few hundred duplicates on SO.)

Comment: @akop Don't assume who downvoted the answer. And I agree that it's not very clear what OP tried to do. That is why I already VTC'd as unclear. The question title says "_Which data type should i use to store a number this large_" where the answer might very well be "String" if you don't need to perform any mathematical operations on the number. That being said, votes measure how useful an answer (or post in general) is to future visitors. This answer is both misleading and already available a few hundred times on SO, so it doesn't yield much value. Downvoting would be very appropriate here.